# When sending a list from controller to ajax, company data type value is not passed

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, jpa

I am in the process of getting all the values ​​of Estmt Entity by receiving an ajax request, and I found the desired value in the controller with jpa findallby

but

When returning the value contained in the list by ajax, the value of the Company data type is not sent by ajax Is there a solution?

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/estmt")
public class EstmtController extends BaseController {

    @Inject
    private EstmtService estmtService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Responses.ListResponse gets(RequestParams<Estmt> requestParams) {
        List<Estmt> list = estmtService.gets(requestParams);
        return Responses.ListResponse.of(list);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.PUT}, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Long save(@RequestBody List<EstmtDTO> request) {
        Long id = estmtService.saveEstmt(request);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class EstmtService extends BaseService<Estmt, Long> {
    private EstmtRepository estmtRepository;

    @Inject
    public EstmtService(EstmtRepository estmtRepository) {
        super(estmtRepository);
        this.estmtRepository = estmtRepository;
    }

    public List<Estmt> gets(RequestParams<Estmt> requestParams) {
        return estmtRepository.findAllBy();
    }
}
```

Estmt Entity

```
@Getter
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "ESTMT")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Estmt extends BaseJpaModel<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ESTMT_ID", precision = 19, nullable = false)

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long estmtId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CMP_ID")
    private Company company;

    @Column(name = "ESTMT_DT")
    private LocalDate estmtDt;

    @Column(name = "CAR", length = 100)
    private String car;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return estmtId;
    }
}
```

Company Entity

```
package com.samin.mes.domain.basicInfo.company;

import com.chequer.axboot.core.code.AXBootTypes;
import com.samin.mes.domain.BaseJpaModel;
import com.samin.mes.domain.basicInfo.company.mtrls.CmpMtrls;
import lombok.*;
import com.chequer.axboot.core.annotations.Comment;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Company extends BaseJpaModel<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CMP_ID", precision = 19, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long cmpId;

    @Column(name = "CMP_NM", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String cmpNm;

    @Column(name = "SEC_CD", length = 20)
    private String secCd;

    @Column(name = "BIZ_NO", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String bizNo;

    @Column(name = "CEO_NM", length = 100)
    private String ceoNm;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @Column(name = "INDUTY", length = 255)
    private String induty;

    @Column(name = "BIZCND", length = 255)
    private String bizcnd;

    @Column(name = "PHONE", length = 20)
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "FAX", length = 20)
    private String fax;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "RSPNS", length = 50)
    private String rspns;

    @Column(name = "ETC", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String etc;

    @Column(name = "USE_YN", length = 1, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "labelEnum")
    private AXBootTypes.Used useYn = AXBootTypes.Used.YES;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<CmpMtrls> cmpMtrlsList;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return this.address == null? new Address() : this.address;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() { return cmpId; }

    public void addMtrls(CmpMtrls cmpMtrls) {
        cmpMtrlsList.add(cmpMtrls);
        cmpMtrls.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

Estimate.js

```
var fnObj = {};
var ACTIONS = axboot.actionExtend(fnObj, {
    PAGE_SEARCH: function (caller, act, data) {
        axboot.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ["estmt"],
            data: $.extend({}, caller.searchView.getData(), caller.gridView01.getPageData()),
            callback: function (res) {
                console.log("res",res);
                caller.gridView01.setData(res);
            }
        });

        return false;
    },
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to make Estmt.company with fetch type eager. Or you can make a call to esmt.getCompany() for each element of can't list in EstmtService.gets

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I solved it using query dsl

Comment: public Page<EstmtDTO> gets(Pageable pageable) {
        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

        QueryResults<Estmt> results = select().from(qEstmt)
                .leftJoin(qEstmt.company, qCompany).fetchJoin()
                .where(builder)
                .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                .fetchResults();

        return new PageImpl<>(results.getResults()
            .stream().map(e -> new EstmtDTO(e))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()), pageable, results.getTotal());
    }